# Is Luc Deveraux still a protagonist in the last Universal Soldier film?

Tags: plot-explanation, universal-soldier

In the *Universal Soldier* franchise Luc Deveraux (mostly played by Jean-Claude Van Damme) is a Universal Soldier created by the government to go on several missions to save the country and its people.

But in the last installment (*Day of Reckoning*), the government looks to be the real villain and Deveraux is still a protagonist who has created a separatist group who seek infiltrating the government; because they feel the gov is responsible for their pain.

At the end, even John himself decided to infiltrate the government.

Is the government the villain of *US:DoR*? Is Deveraux a protagonist?

Comment: Given that his role is basically an extended cameo to allow them to put his face on the poster, I'd say that he's not the protagonist; "*the leading character or one of the major characters in a play, film, novel, etc.*". This all seems very opinion-based though. You could argue that his presence looms large even when he's not on screen since most of the action is about him, like Kurtz in Apocalypse Now.

Comment: But government is the villain. We can also say that Deveraux is a good guy (or an anti-hero) even if we don't call him a protagonist.

Comment: In real life and on film...

Comment: Not on all films. In the past installments of the franchise government was good. And on so many other films.

Comment: IIRC doesn't US:DoR start with Deveraux and some other thugs executing a man's wife and daughter? Doesn't seem very heroic to me.

Comment: @kingofpanes It is revealed in the movie that the wife and daughter aren't real. They are just false implanted memories in John's mind. The memories are implanted by the government so that he goes on a mission to hunt the rebel Deveraux. John is a cloned UniSol which are created by the government. Deveraux simply didn't want to be in this exploiting system anymore (he himself was also a UniSol before). So he separated and created a group to fight against the government. John himself turned against the government when he found the truth at the end.

Comment: Also, the hallucinations of Deveraux that cloned UniSols experienced when injected by the serum wasn't for a villainy. But it was for the greater good; to eliminate the government's control on them. to convince them to join Deveraux in his separatist group. The only side effect is a temporary madness. John also was once injected in the movie, but he overpowered the hallucination.

Comment: Near the end of the movie Deveraux allowed John to kill him after a brief fight. Because he realized John is the best person to succeed him as the leader of the group. John became the group's leader at the end. But why did he kill Deveraux at all? He first had entered the group under the ground to get help erasing the false memories. But he went mad in the process and as a result he killed many group members in his way until he reached Deveraux himself.